# React.js change page

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, react-hooks

I code a login panel and need to change pages by `history.Push()` but there is an error which is:

> React Hook "useHistory" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

```
    import react from 'react';
    import{landingPage, adminPage} from './components';
    import { Route,Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
    import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
    import {routes} from './components/routes'

    const history = useHistory();
    class App extends react.Component{
      handlepageChange = (activePage) => {
        history.push(activePage);
      }
      render(){
        const {landing, admin} = routes;
        return(
          <div className="App">
            <Router history ={history}>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path = {landing.path}>
                  <landingPage handlepageChange = {this.handlepageChange}/>
                </Route>
                <Route exact path={admin.path}>
                  <adminPage handlepageChange ={this.handlepageChange}/>
                </Route>
              </Switch>
            </Router>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Error is in

> `const history = useHistory();`

and

> `<Router history = {history}>`

How can I change pages after login and fix error

Comment: It sounds like you need to spend some time learning what [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) are, and how [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) works.

Comment: Short summary: hooks are for use in the *body of function components* **only**. You should probably be using `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom` which creates the `history` object for you. And then you may use `history` in children components (not in `App`).

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to other component using `this.props.history.push(activePage)` in class component

Comment: They can't do that here. `history` has to be put into props by something, it doesn't just magically appear. There are fundamental misunderstandings in the OP's code that need to be addressed before a simple answer can be given.